# Delphi - tfilestream: write time and date to file

Tags: delphi, tfilestream

I am trying to save a line for each event containing a piece of text and the time + date when happened.

The problem is:

1. time is shown as Chinese font
2. it replaces the same line over and over again

Here is the code:

```
    uses sysUtils, classes;

function log: Boolean;
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  i : String;
  time : TDateTime;

begin
  i := 'Boss is dead!';
  time := now;
  try
    fs := TFileStream.Create('log.txt', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);
    fs.Write(PChar(i +TimeToStr(time))^, Length(i +TimeToStr(time)));
    fs.write(i, sizeof(i));   
  finally
    fs.Free; 
  end;

end;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you expect Latin text, but see Chinese text, that means that you are interpreting ANSI text as though it were UTF-16. From this I infer that you are intending to write out UTF-16 text, but are actually writing out ANSI text. Which means that you have a pre-Unicode Delphi.

As far as why you keep overwriting the file, then that's because you pass `fmCreate`. What you really want to do is open an existing file in write mode, or if no file exists, create a new file. The Win32 API function supports that with the `OPEN_ALWAYS` creation disposition. But that is not available through `TFileStream.Create`. So you have to use `THandleStream` and call `CreateFile` directly. Note that newer versions of Delphi introduce `TFile.Open` that exposes `OPEN_ALWAYS` functionality. But my reasoning says you are using a Delphi that is too old.

Assuming that you can use `THandleStream`, and call `CreateFile` correctly, then you just need to write out UTF-16 text. The simplest way is to use a `WideString`. You might write the code like this:

```
var
  ws: WideString;
....
Stream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
ws := TimeToStr(Now) + sLineBreak;
Stream.WriteBuffer(PWideChar(ws)^, SizeOf(WideChar)*Length(ws));
```

On the other hand, perhaps the Chinese comes from here:

```
fs.write(i, sizeof(i));
```

This code simply writes a pointer to the file. You for sure don't want to do that and should remove that line. For sake of completeness, if you do have a Unicode Delphi, then you would write the text in a quite similar way. Like this:

```
var
  s: string;
....
Stream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
s := TimeToStr(Now) + sLineBreak;
Stream.WriteBuffer(PWideChar(s)^, SizeOf(WideChar)*Length(s));
```

Going back to appending to a stream, that would run like this:

```
var
  hFile: THandle;
....
hFile := CreateFile(
  PChar(LogFileName),
  GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ,
  nil,
  OPEN_ALWAYS,
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
  0
);
Win32Check(hFile<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
Try
  Stream := THandleStream.Create(hFile);
  Try
    .... code to write to the stream goes here
  Finally
    Stream.Free;
  End;
Finally
  CloseHandle(hFile);
End;
```

Finally, I have had to make a lot of guesses about your environment in this answer. In future, always include the Delphi version that you use. And always include a clear statement of your goals.

Comment: You answer helps to fix the current implementation with a nice explanation, so my +1 for that. However, I somehow think that the OP should take a step back and take another approach, by sticking to higher level wrappers that are provided in the framework. They're cross-platform, and are most likely to still work in the future.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick Asker has a pre-Unicode Delphi that doesn't have the high level wrappers. Hence my answer.

Comment: @David It could be he has D2009+, in which case there's two errors: 1) In first `write()` he outputs Length() bytes instead of 2 * Length(). Output is 'Boss is dea'. 2) In second write he outputs the *address* of `i` which shows up as chinalese and appended to previous output, he thinks is the time.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes, I suppose that is plausible.

Comment: If D2009+ is being used, you can use `ByteLength(s)` instead of `SizeOf(WideChar)*Length(s)`. Or, use `TStreamWriter` instead of `TFileStream.WriteBuffer()` directly. That has the added benefit that you can specify the desired encoding of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that I'd change about your code.

1. You've got a function that's supposed to return a boolean, but you never set a return value.
2. It's not "wrong", but variable `i` is most commonly used as an integer index to an array, or as a loop variable. Delphi developers are going to hate code that uses `i` as a string.
3. It looks like you're just logging text. TFileStream is probably not the best class to do that.

I think this is much cleaner code:

```
uses System.IoUtils;

...

FileName := 'log.txt';
LogLine  := 'Boss is dead '+TimeToStr(Now);

TFile.AppendAllText(FileName, LogLine);
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText

Comment: If ASCII characters appear as Chinese, given that code, then it's safe to conclude that the asker has a pre-Unicode Delphi

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're probably right... Poor asker :) IoUtils was introduced in Delphi... 2010?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
uses SysUtils;

var s: AnsiString;

s := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', now);
fs.Write(s[1], Length(s));
```

Comment: You've not addressed the issue of text encoding

Comment: I think I did, although not explicitly. Please note that:
1. Using AnsiString ensures that plain 8-bit strings are used
2. The date formatting string results in plain numbers, without any month or day names which might require special characters depending on the language.
3. The resulting string will be written correctly by the stream. Even if the "log.txt" file is utf-8, the result will still be correct since the string is only numbers and dashes.

Comment: The user reports that the file appears to contain Chinese text.

Comment: User reports _time_ is shown as Chinese text. I'm suggesting an alternative way of writing the time to the stream which I believe ought to solve that problem.

Comment: It appears Chinese because the text that is written is ANSI, but when read the file is interpreted as being UTF-16 encoded.